# How to make user edit data in business data list?

Tags: 2010, external-content-type, business-data-catalog

I set up a business data list to get data from SQL server through external content type. It works very well and users are able to see the data from SQL server on their SharePoint UI.

But now I'm wondering is there anyway to grant user ability to edit the data in business data list? And naturally any update occurred in SharPoint site should also affect the data in SQL server.

If the answer is no, what's the best way to grant user ability to edit SQL server data on SharePoint UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out:

First create an external content type, and add read list, create item, update item and delete item operations to that content type based on your table or stored procedure in SQL server (I do not suggest using view since SQL cannot update data to multiple tables at once).

Then in SPD’s external content type menu, right click your external content type, and create external list. This list is editable and any update will directly reflect to SQL server database.